# Remember previous directory when adding existing resource

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I have a collection of numerous icons, png files and other graphics data stored on a Icons folder in my secondary hard disk.
When I need a new resource I double click on the resource.resx file and add the new one via 'Add Existing file".
However each time I use this menu, it opens a browse window initially located at **C:\Windows\System32**. So, each time, I need to go to my Icons folder.
Is there a way to 'teach' Visual Studio how to remember the last folder opened? (Macro? Addin?)

Comment: Just curious. Downvoter, what have you found wrong in my question after 9 months?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has annoyed me for quite some time, and just found this via a Google search. I voted it up, but per Microsoft's response on the bug page, it's unlikely it will ever get fixed(it might take all of 5 minutes, after all)...

Anyways, I did find a suitable work-around for my scenario that I wanted to share!  Simply use Explorer to navigate to the path with your resources(icons, pngs, etc.) and drag/drop them into the resource list in VS2010. This is actually faster for me, as I have PNG's and an icon for each graphic I add, and this way I can add both with one step, instead of switching between the 'icon' resource section and the 'images' resource section, clicking 'Add Resource'->Existing->find path->select, etc... Hopefully this saves someone considerable time, as it's saved me.

Comment: Why I have not seen your answer? OK I have just reached your same approach all by myself, but I accept your answer

Comment: Link to [bug report](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/811451/visual-studio-2013-dialog-add-existing-file-does-not-remember-its-current-folder) at Microsoft.